# What does ^{ mean?

Tags: clojure

In the following code, I have noticed the `^` character before what seems to be a map data structure. What is `^` used for, or what is `^{` used for?

```
(ns temper.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [mount.core :as mount]))

(mount/defstate ^{:on-reload :noop}
                http-server
                :start
                (http/start
                 (-> env
                     (assoc :handler (lazy-run 'temper.handler 'app))
                     (update :port #(or (-> env :options :port) %))))
                :stop
                (http/stop http-server))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` character is for metadata. Please see https://clojure.org/reference/reader#macrochars and https://clojure.org/reference/metadata.

`^{:on-reload :noop}` and `(with-meta obj {:on-reload :noop})` are equivalent.

Comment: This is one of the few "reader macros" in Clojure. You can find a complete list here: https://clojure.org/reference/reader

Comment: I tried to find those character combinations on clojuredocs but they did not show up in the search box. I will raise it on GitHub now.